# How to insert a video into the web page without showing the player?

Tags: html, video, web

I'm trying to insert a video in my webpage without showing any player control on it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the video **controls** attribute.

**P.S.** Okay then, I hope it works out like you want it to:

```
<iframe id="ytdiv" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wZGenX_Vwk0?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;HD=1" frameborder="0" width="650" height="350"></iframe>
<div id="backgrounddiv" style="background-color:transparent;">
</div>
<style>
    #backgrounddiv{width:650px;
    height:350px;position:relative;}
    #ytdiv{
        position:absolute;z-index:-1;
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZxXT/1/

Comment: Until now I used the youtube player and I can't remove the video controls. What do you suggest to use?